# Error in reading csv file SparkR in windows

Tags: r, csv, sparkr

I'm using SparkR in windows 7 machine.When I read CSV file which has fewer rows than 2000 then it works but when number of rows exceed 2000 it gives error.

I'm using the following code

```
library(SparkR)   

sc <- sparkR.init(master="local")  

sqlContext <- sparkRSQL.init(sc)

localDF<-fread("train.csv",nrows=1e6)

localDF<-as.data.frame(localDF)

df <- createDataFrame(sqlContext, localDF)
```

Comment: You may be memory bound.

Comment: Its 8 GB windows machine..